# Python process blocking socket [Errno 98]

Tags: python, sockets

I'm running two raspis connected to each other. They both run a program on startup (which starts fine).
However, I keep getting a `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use` error in the background, and the communication between both Pis doesn't even start.

I went for tracing down the python processes running via `ps -fA ¦ grep python` and tadaaa, I can see, that another process starts trying to use the same address. 
The output of `ps` looks like:

```
root      923  917  0  12:25 pts/1   00:00:00 sudo python /home/pi/Documents/3_multithread.py
root      927  923  10 12:25 pts/1   00:00:00 python /home/pi/Documents/3_multithread.py
pi        932  881  0  12:25 pts/0   00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
```

From what I understand is, that it looks like the same process (3_multithread.py) is called twice (once as su, once not as su).

EDIT#2: I start the program via the .bashrc (sudo python /home/pi/Documents/3_multithread.py) and a lxsession. Might this be the reason for blocking the address?

The errorlog looks like that:

```
File "/home/pi/Documents/3_multithread.py", line 276, in set_server bind((HOST, PORT))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth return getattr(self._sock, name)(*args)
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I just also checked the `netstat -lptn`. I get the following output:

```
tcp        0     0 0.0.0.0:22           0.0.0.0.*          LISTEN     -
```

EDIT#123: I traced the error further down. I imported and printed:

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

To get the process PID. Now what happens is: On bootup my script returned the PID `754`, while the `ps -fA ¦ grep python` only stats two python processes with the PIDs `535` and `539`. Does `.bashrc` and `lxterminal` start the process twice?

This is how i configure my socket inside the python script

```
def set_server():
    global conn_global
    global socket_global
    global conn_established
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 22
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    socket_global = s
    conn_global = conn
    conn_established = 1
```

I'm using global variables to send commands to send the commands to the other Pi, which is working absolutely perfect (once the connection is established).

Thank you guys very much in advance!
With best regards,
Tobi

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details : the ps output, in what way  do you start your program, etc

Comment: How did you see that other process is using the same address/port from `ps`? `netstat` is the tool for that.

Comment: Do not use .bashrc to start scripts. Every time you start a new shell, you will launch a new process. I am highly doubtful this is your intention.

Comment: The program will run on startup, and the user will just interact with the open program, not with the pi itself. So there will only be one open terminal/session. Also, @lxterminal is called only once from the lxsession. So there should only be one process running?

Comment: Maybe it is fine then. What you describe in your process table is a completely normal output when you sudo a command. The first process (923) is sudo, and process 927 is your actual script. So it is running only once. If there is a socket conflict, it is caused by either the port being used by another process (lsof or netstat -an can help you with that), or you have just killed your own process and started it again, and you have not set socket.SO_REUSEADDR to your socket. If you do not have SO_REUSEADDR, your socket will be unavailable for about two minutes in *_WAIT states

Comment: I eddited my socket setup into the post. I'm using the SO_REUSEADDR already. However i figured out, that after around 10 seconds the script passes the s.bind(HOST, PORT) and is waiting at s.accept() without any connection being established (even if i unplug the network cable). And then it is throwing the Errno 98

Comment: Which function raises the exception? Bind or accept? Could you please add a bit more code? Bind is not supposed to be  blocking. Accept should. And then we would be interested in what happens afterwards when you have accepted a connection. By all means add more lines of code to your question. If there is no conflict (someone else is using the same port number), then you are not using sockets right, and from these three lines it is impossible to know.

Comment: Are you sure there is no sshd running on the pi?

Comment: On this pi, I have disabled ssh in the raspi configurations. I just also ran sudo systemctl disable ssh. The error still occurs

Comment: If you run netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 22      do you get any results? If not, then I do not know. Your code looks ok.  But I would not use a reserved port anyway. Try changing the port number to 4222 or something like that and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, I get the output, I just eddited in my post

Comment: Ok. Then there is something there listening to that port. Use lsof to see what process it is. If you just disabled sshd, it might be still running but would not start at next boot. Try lsof -P | grep \\*:22 and see what the offending process is.

Comment: I tried the restart - still the same. And lsof doesnt work. It keeps throwing: 'bash: lsof: command not found'

Comment: I'm installing lsof atm

Comment: Is there a reason to use a well-known and universally reserved port for your own communication protocol? To me this is a recipe for a lot of issues, portability problems, remote management problems and a lot of extra work in general. If you need a privileged port, use 1001 for example. It should be free.

Comment: I tried running lsof -P | grep \*:22, but there is no return on that. It just runs the command and nothing happens. Is that how its supposed to work?

Comment: If you had a backslash \ in front of the asterisk, then  yes. If that is the case, there should not be anything running on 22 anymore. Sorry, I cannot help more as this is just guesswork.

Comment: yes i got the \ there. Seems like nothing is running there anymore, but something is still blocking the port.
I tried using the 1001 port now and rebooted. Still the same address in use error.

Comment: If anyone is still on here, I edited the post again. Maybe Hannu was right, and its the .bashrc?

Comment: Good you were able to sort out the problem. I sort of thought .bashrc is not the ideal place to start things that must only run once as every subshell ever executed would run the script.  If you want to run your app at boot as root, you should examine making it a service instead. This is the "correct" unix way of doing things. Then your script will start without user interaction as the system boots. And if your script dies for some reason, it will be automatically restarted if you so desire.

Comment: Ok, that sounds interesting aswell. I might do that in a future application. I'm just glad this one is running now smoothly. Do you have any links or so where i could read more about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was FINALLY able to solve that issue.

As Hannu suggested first, the problem was the way I booted the system. First of all, what did I want to do?

I need to boot both Raspis into the X environment (Graphical user interface), since both of my Pis are running a Tkinter GUI. That's why I went for the lxsession based autostart solution. Using the .bashrc file to start my python code failed, since it looked like the .bashrc is called twice on boot. 
So what solved my issue was, to use a shell script to start the python code on bootup from a lxterminal.

In order to do this:

1. Create a shell script in your home directory (the tilde ~ directory)

   `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nano start.sh`

and add the hashbang as well as the command to start your python script

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo python ~/Your/file/here.py
```

2. Edit the user LX autostart file like:

   `sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

and add the call for the lxterminal including your shell script like

```
@lxterminal -e ./start.sh
```

Finally, for my application I had to grant access rights to everyone

```
chmod 775 start.sh
```

and use global file paths for all images, like

```
/home/Documents/Your/files/here.png
```

Save everything and reboot your pi. Now Everything should boot up perfectly.
Thank you all for helping me, especially Hannu!

Comment: Glad this worked for you. I missed this conversation, however, please note that in general scripts to run after boot should simply be put in /etc/rc.local. If you need to start/stop it as a service, you modify a service script template in /etc/init.d and add the script to proper runlevel. For more on latter approach, see about linux runlevels, eg https://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/769-linux-runlevels-explained

Comment: I tried the rc.local approach before. However I was running in a $DISPLAY error (probably due to the use of Tkinter) then, which was kind of weird. So I tried to start my script - after the system booted completely - from a terminal. And this is what I ended up with. As I said, it works fine for now. However, I will try the rc.local approach again when I have time for that. Thank you a lot! :-)

Comment: ah, you have a desktop app which requires X to run? Didn't realise that. In that case you are right, rc.local and /or services are not likely to work well - you need to have an active X session to attach to, but the /etc approach is usually meant for system wide things that don't use X input/output.

Comment: Yes, both Pis are running a TKinter user interface, thats why I thought the easiest way would be to go for the lxterminal (to be absolutely sure everything booted properly). I was kind of frustrated trying to find the right runlevel :-D. Thats why I tried it as late as possible.

Comment: No, if you have a desktop app, I would say it only makes sense to run it from X session startup -- else there is no sense -- what display can the app show upon, if there is no active X session anywhere. I think others may have assumed, like me, that it was a server/console app (as is more frequently the case when we talk about app connecting to another computer on its own).